# Run command for all videos in a directory

Tags: bash, scripts, video-editor

I have multiple video files ending in .mp4 in a directory. I would like to add our advertisement message to each video intro example.mp4 to the front and end of each video. I can do this manually for each video using the example below

```
mkvmerge -o 'RANDOM VIDEO NAME.mp4' 'intro example.mp4' \+ 'RANDOM VIDEO NAME.mp4' \+ 'intro example.mp4'
```

How can I do this for every video in a specific folder? and then save the video that has the intro at the start and end to a specific folder. The file also must be saved in the new folder with the same name as the original file.

This question is not a duplicate as linked below due to the file names staying the same

Comment: The above possible duplicates don't include keeping the same file name

Comment: @Toodarday that's just a trivial variation, reuse `{}` in case of `find` or the relevant variable in case of shell loops.